# Can't Flattr an auto submit URL via the REST API

Tags: flattr

When flattring an auto submit URL via the REST V2 API with this request

```
POST https://api.flattr.com/rest/v2/flattr

{"url":"https://flattr.com/submit/auto?user_id=myuserid&url=myurl"}
```

I get this error, although the URL works fine in any browser and redirects to the existing thing.

```
{
  "error_description" : "The requested thing(s) could not be found",
  "error_uri" : "http:\/\/developers.flattr.net\/api",
  "error" : "not_found"
}
```

So either I'm doing something wrong, or the error message is wrong, or something else?

Comment: Can you please supply a little more information?

Comment: I'm successfully authenticating in an iOS app using gtm-oauth2, I set the scope to "flattr". When I then try the request above, it fails. When I use the same auto submit URL in a browser, it works fine and redirects to the existing thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have a problem with url encoding. For this to work you need to URL encode first the autosubmit URL.

`http://blog.flattr.net/2011/10/api-v2-beta-out-whats-changed/` becomes `http%3A%2F%2Fblog.flattr.net%2F2011%2F10%2Fapi-v2-beta-out-whats-changed%2F`

Then you need to URL encode the whole autosubmit URL if you want to send it as a regular POST request.

`http://flattr.com/submit/auto?url=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.flattr.net%2F2011%2F10%2Fapi-v2-beta-out-whats-changed%2F&user_id=flattr` becomes `http%3A%2F%2Fflattr.com%2Fsubmit%2Fauto%3Furl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fblog.flattr.net%252F2011%252F10%252Fapi-v2-beta-out-whats-changed%252F%26user_id%3Dflattr`.

If you are going to send it with JSON you don't need to URL encode the flattr autosubmit URL. Instead you do like the example below.

`{"url":"http://flattr.com/submit/auto?url=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.flattr.net%2F2011%2F10%2Fapi-v2-beta-out-whats-changed%2F&user_id=flattr"}`

This means that part of the URL will be URL encoded two times if you do a regular POST request and if you will send the data as JSON URL encode only one time. And when you do POST request with JSON body you need to set the `Content-Type` to `application/json` to make it work.

Comment: Your example URL still throws an error:{
  "error_description" : "The request is invalid",
  "error_uri" : "http:\/\/developers.flattr.net\/api",
  "error" : "invalid_request"
}

Comment: I tried your URL as shown above, as well as the auto submit URL with the &user= parameter

Comment: Ah, I see that I forgot to add a user_id to the request. I will look into adding better error descriptions tomorrow.

Comment: And I see that I missed a thing in the description. Check out the JSON body example.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to set the Content-type header for the request. It needs to say "application/json".